# LAMP server VM issues

Tags: vmware-player, samba, lamp, virtual-machines

After getting a [recommendation to salvage a wiki by installing a LAMP server](https://serverfault.com/questions/46617/setting-up-a-wiki-from-raw-files), [I went on the prowl for a good virtualized one](http://virtualappliances.net/products/lamp.php). I used the VMware Player version. Since the windows box has Bonjour, I can, for example, go to http://lamp.local. and it works see the web client. The problem is, I can't ssh to a directory to scp the files I need, mount a usb thumbdrive (usbfs is unsupported) nor get samba working. I can't even update the ubuntu installation, it fails.

I've tried bridged, nat and host-only networking settings in VMware Player. Bridged gives me an undefined IP, while the other two each have different IPs. All three settings allow me to access the web config, but none of them give me samba access. Windows usually freezes, then reports that it cannot connect.

I'd rather not wipe a box to do a dedicated install, is there I way I can get this VM working, or are there better LAMP VMs out there? This one came already working and set up with VMware Player, so I thought it would be perfect...

Thanks,

Comment: Did you check the firewall config on the LAMP appliance? I am always leery of other peoples undocumented configurations.

Comment: What happens when you attempt to SSH and update the Ubuntu installation?  Do you get any error messages or does it just fail.

Answer (score 1):

I use [VMware Server](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/) on an Ubuntu host system for a variety of testing purposes. I'm using bridged networking for clients that are running a wide array of web server tasks such as "LAMP" stacks, Ruby on Rails and Django test applications.

I haven't used VMware Player, but it strikes me as a tool to run VMs created by other VMware products, but not actually *do* much with them as far as managing devices that are connected, or changing networking options.

Comment: Right, the options are light, but it came prebuilt - with instruction on how to connect to it via samba/http, it just isn't working the way they described. I guesss I'll have to work something out on VMware server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [AWS Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/) VMs. They have some public LAMP images already. They connect by ssh and scp.